# Query to sum & count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

My data is something like this

```
Count   years
1     2020-08-11
1    2020-07-11
1    2019-09-01
1    2019-08-16
1    2019-05-04
1    2018-06-11
```

I'm writing a query where I have to find the count of year for eg <= 04 May 2019
,I need to find the count of all the dates lesser than that date i.e '2019-05-04'
count will come as 1  and then add 1 to the count.

I've written the query like this:

```
with sum_count as(
    select count(*) as 'Counts', years from [practice].[dbo].[People]
    where years<='2019-05-04'
    group by years)

    select sum(Counts) + 1 as Sum
    from  sum_count
```

Could you please help to do the same for all the dates like for 2020-08-11
the count shall come as 5 and sum a 6

Comment: Please specify which DBMS.

Comment: Hi nifriz I'm writing the query in sql server

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this quite simply by a select statement without the need for a cte:

```
Declare @td datetime = '20190504' 
SELECT COUNT([years])+1 FROM [practice].[dbo].[People] Where [years] <= @td
```

If this something you would be repeating a lot you can have it as a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROC proc_name (@dt datetime)
as    SELECT COUNT([years])+1 FROM [practice].[dbo].[People] Where [years] <= @td
```

and you would call it as such

```
exec proc_name ('20200801')
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the answer , how can I modify the query if i need to pass  all the dates  dynamically as I need to do the same for all the dates.

Comment: not sure I follow your question. In the first example above you can pass the dates simply by changing the variable. So for example if you run the same query and pass '20180505' it will return results based on that date.

Same for the stored procedure option, you just call it and pass the date you want

Comment: If you explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve this can be done very simply, where are the dynamic dates coming from?

Comment: any joy with suggestions above?

Answer (score 0):

Writing procedure can be one way, but if your hell bent on using a query you can use this.

```
select count(1)+1 as sum,a.year1
from
    (
    select distinct year as year1
    from [practice].[dbo].[People]
    
    ) a 
    inner join 
    [practice].[dbo].[People] b on b.year<=a.year1
    group by a.year1
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: Hi Aldrin, thanks a lot for your help... when I'm executing the above query ,I'm getting this error in the db ..Below is the error mesage                                                                       
 Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ')'. could you please help me out

Comment: edited the answer...i was misssing "from " in query..let me know if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you simply want a window function.  The following enumerates each row within each year:

```
select p.*,
       row_number() over (partition by year(years) order by years) as seqnum
from [practice].[dbo].[People] p;
```

No stored procedure or auxiliary function is necessary.